# Insert cells into a section of an already statically created table

Tags: ios, objective-c, forms, uitableview

I am creating an iOS app that has a form to create a certain 'event'. This form is wrapped in a tableview. This tableview consists of static cells. But there is one section in the table that can be used to add persons to this event and thus on a button press a new tableview cell needs to be inserted at that section. To demonstrate this see the following image:

[image]

What I want to know is how to insert cells into a static table. And also how to grab them when the user submits the form, since, as far as I'm concerned, you can't grab a specific section of a table.

I already looked at this kind of concept but this does not apply on adding cells:

[Mixing static and dynamic sections in a grouped table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607240/mixing-static-and-dynamic-sections-in-a-grouped-table-view)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are (at least) 2 workarounds for this:

1. You could add a dynamic UITableView as a child to the UITableViewCell. See [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell) about this.
2. An other solution would be to bypass the table functionality in that cell and change the height of the cell and add the extra controls manually.

Comment: More useful answer. I am going for the second approach :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to add or remove cells at runtime, you'll need to use a data source for your tableview. I asked a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941813/deleting-rows-from-a-static-uitableview-at-runtime), with no luck.

In response to your second question, you can always grab cells using the [`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:) on `UITableView`.

Comment: Sad enough this is the correct answer. I am going to use one cell and make that cell higher each time a person is added.